# you vs yourself?

Tags: grammaticality, pronouns

Please help me with grammaticality or acceptability of the two sentences:

A) No one is better at persuading yourself than you.
B) No one is better at persuading you than yourself.

Which is correct?

Answer (score 2):

Only **you** can persuade **yourself**, so if a comparison with other people is being made A doesn't work.

Personally, I would say

> No one is better at persuading you than you are yourself.

Comment: ... or 'No one is better at persuading you than you yourself [are].'